# 2 accepted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

The question [Как удалить элемент из выпадающего списка с помощью jQuery?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/401754/15479) ([wayback machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20170328125544/https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/401754/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery)) has two accepted answers:

> [image: Two accepted answers]

This is probably because of the migration from http://hashcode.ru. This still hasn't been fixed after three years.

Discussion on our meta: [Два принятых ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2047/15479).